# DAG Integrity Test - AttributeError: 'DAG' object has no attribute 'test_cycle'

Tags: pytest, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have been trying to implement the DAG Integrity Test from Data Pipelines with apache airflow:

```
import glob
import importlib.util
import os
import pytest
from airflow.models import DAG

DAG_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "..", "dags/**/dag*")
DAG_FILES = glob.glob(DAG_PATH, recursive=True)
print(DAG_FILES)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("dag_file", DAG_FILES)
def test_dag_integrity(dag_file):
    module_name, _ = os.path.splitext(dag_file)
    module_path = os.path.join(DAG_PATH, dag_file)
    mod_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(mod_spec)
    mod_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    dag_objects = [var for var in vars(module).values() if isinstance(var, DAG)]
    assert dag_objects
    for dag in dag_objects:
        dag.test_cycle()
```

But when I do I get this error:

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("dag_file", DAG_FILES)
    def test_dag_integrity(dag_file):
        module_name, _ = os.path.splitext(dag_file)
        module_path = os.path.join(DAG_PATH, dag_file)
        mod_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
        module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(mod_spec)
        mod_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
        dag_objects = [var for var in vars(module).values() if isinstance(var, DAG)]
        assert dag_objects
        for dag in dag_objects:
>           dag.test_cycle()
E           AttributeError: 'DAG' object has no attribute 'test_cycle'
```

I get this Attribute Error for every dag im trying to test. I have been looking around trying to find a fix for this, but sofar I have come up short.

Comment: which version of airflow are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The DAG object no longer has the `test_cycle()` method, instead there's a separate utility script.

Add:

`from airflow.utils.dag_cycle_tester import test_cycle as dag_test_cycle`

And then replace your line `dag.test_cycle()` with `dag_test_cycle(dag)`